# Unable to find the specific items value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing an easy problem but unable to find a solution  the problem is

i am creating a dynamic div with some elements also with some data

```
$("#divSearchedIssue").append(`
<div class="statistic d-flex align-items-center bg-white has-shadow">
  <div class="icon bg-red">
    <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="text">

    ***//want to get this below id value//**

    Mobile Code :
    <small id="mbCode"> 
      ${ data[0].MobileCode }
    </small>

    ***/want to find/**

    <br>
    Failed From:
    <small>
      ${ data[0].FailedStation }
    </small>

    <br>
    Issues :
    <small>
      ${ data[0].Issues }
    </small>
  </div>
  <div class="text"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div>
  <div class="text">
    <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Start</button>
  </div>
  <div class="text"><br></div>
</div>`);
```

Here I have a button .On this button click i want to fetch the value of 
 small text which id is **#mbCode** as mentioned above inside the code

I am trying this by using the following button click code

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {
    var data = $(this).closest('small').find('#mbCode').val();
    alert(data);
});
```

but its not working.I mean I cant fetch the value of #mbCode on this button click .So help needed 
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself ***and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.***

***As `<small>` is not an ancestors to button in hierarchy(while traversing-up)***,

So You need to first go the parent of `<small>` through `.closest()` and then try to find `<small>` html using `.find()` and `.html()`

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {
    var data = $(this).closest('.statistic').find('small').html();
    alert(data);
});
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
data = [{'MobileCode':20,'FailedStation':'WATERLOO','Issues':'broken'}];
$("#divSearchedIssue").append('<div class="statistic d-flex align-items- center bg-white has-shadow"><div class="icon bg-red"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i></div><div class="text">Mobile Code :<small id="mbCode">' + data[0].MobileCode + '</small><br>Failed From: <small> ' + data[0].FailedStation + '</small><br>Issues :<small> '+ data[0].Issues + '</small></div><div class="text"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></div><div class="text"><button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Start</button></div><div class="text"><br></div></div>');

$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {
  var data = $(this).closest('.statistic').find('small').each(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSearchedIssue"></div>
```

***Note:- `.text()` will work too***

https://jsfiddle.net/tyz4ox50/

Comment: Yes! now I get it i was searching inside the button instead of searching from the parent !. Thank you sir @Alive to Die

Answer (score 1):

As identifiers must be *unique*, Directly use [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) with `.text()`/`.html()` method

```
var data = $('#mbCode').text()
```

However if you are appending multiple elements I would recommend an alternative to persist *Mobile code* arbitrary data using custom `data-*` attribute along with `<button>` which can be fetched using `.data(key)` and attach event handler using [Class Selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$("#divSearchedIssue").append('<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" data-mobilecode="' +   data[0].MobileCode + '" >Start</button>');
```

```js
var counter = 0;

function append() {
  $("#divSearchedIssue").append('<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" data-mobilecode="' + ++counter + '" >Start</button>');
}
append();
append();
append();


$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
  var data = $(this).data('mobilecode');
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSearchedIssue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet

```
var value = $('#mbCode').val();
```

Make sure the `id` is unique

Answer (score 0):

`Id`s shouldn't be duplicate in an web-page.

Also, `small` is not one of the parent nodes of `btn`s, and use `html` instead of `val`.

You need to **go two-level higher** to `statistic` Make it

```
$(document).on('click', '.text #btn', function () {
    var data = $(this).closest('.statistic').find('#mbCode');        
    console.log(data.html());
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var counter = 0;

function append() {
  $("#divSearchedIssue").append(
    `<div class="statistic d-flex align-items- 
center bg-white has-shadow">
<div class="icon bg-red"><i class="fa fa-tasks">
</i></div>
<div class="text">
Mobile Code :<small id="mbCode">` +
    (counter++) +
    `</small><br>Failed From: <small> ' + 
data[0].FailedStation + '</small><br>Issues :<small> ' + data[0].Issues + 
'</small></div>
<div class="text"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
</div>
<div class="text"><button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-
warning pull-right">Start</button></div>
<div class="text"><br></div>
</div>`
  );
}
append();
append();
append();

$(document).on('click', '.text #btn', function () {
    var data = $(this).closest('.statistic').find('#mbCode');        
    console.log(data.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divSearchedIssue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your element already has an ID attribute you should be able to find the element by the ID. $("#mbCode")

Your js code

```
$(this).closest('small').find('#mbCode').val(); // "$(this)", in your code, represents the "button" that was clicked.
```

is looking for "small" tag inside "button" element, but it's not there. It would work if your button was like

```
<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-warning pull-right"><small id="mbCode"></small></button>
```

This should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {
    var $mbCode = $('#mbCode');
    console.log($mbCode);
});
```